# show only few lines after match pattern found in vi editor

Tags: search, vi

I would like to see only `first 5 lines  after the match found` in vi editor. What is the command?

I only know these commands

**`/Incident Id:`**  *Gives all lines from first to last*

**`:g/Incident ID:`**  gives only the match word hiding all non match

But how to show   first 5 lines after the match word found... ?

---

**Example** with expected output :

i have text of 8 lines, & i search for **Incident ID**

```
    Incident ID: 1392875740716  <<<Match word here
    URL: /Project/jsps/ErrorPage.jsp
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1092)
            at com.cando.restaurant.utils.DateRange.createForWeek(DateRange.java:54)
            at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor :110)
            at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation 
            at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor
```

**Expected output**

```
  Incident ID: 1392875740716  <<<Match word here
    URL: /Project/jsps/ErrorPage.jsp
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1092)
            at com.cando.restaurant.utils.DateRange.createForWeek(DateRange.java:54)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you open  a file named `abcd` with vi.So to show only the first 5 lines, you will use,

```
vi ./abcd |head -5
```

If all output is considered as single line, use

```
vi ./abcd | sed s/\n/\n./g | head -5
```

This command will add a dot at every newline.

Comment: i asked with search result

Comment: Then replace `vi ./abcd` with your command.for example `history | head -5`